# LWC Checkbox to stay checked and not able to uncheck

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to create a LWC Checkbox that only is checked and not have the ability to uncheck. Here is my code right now that still allows it to be unchecked.

```
<template>
<div class="nds-form-element">
    <div class="nds-form-element__control">
      <label class="nds-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" checked="checked">
        <span class="nds-checkbox_faux"></span>
        <label class="nds-checkbox__label">
          <span class="nds-form-element__label">Use as Mailing Address</span>
        </label>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
    import { LightningElement } from "lwc";


export default class checkboxOverrideMemberInformation extends LightningElement {

  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the `lightning-input` component, documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example).  Specifically, you are interested in the checkbox type.

`<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Disabled option" name="input3" checked disabled></lightning-input>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes do not have a read only attribute, so, your best shot is to add a change handler that sets the element to checked regardless of its current state.